# Foundation - Opening a modal upon closing another modal

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I have a web page that opens a reveal modal on load, and in this modal, I have a link that can open a 2nd modal. When the 2nd modal closes (either by clicking the close button, or by clicking outside the modal), I would like to reopen the first.

For the close button, I can do it via adding a `data-reveal-id` to the link that has the `close-reveal-modal` class. But when I try to bind to the `close` property, the 1st modal opens, but then the background changes back to normal, and the 1st modal can no longer be closed by clicking outside the modal. Then, on closing the 1st modal with the close button, the whole screen darkens as though a modal was opening. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

My code is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $("#modal2").foundation("reveal", {
        close: function() {
            $("#modal1").foundation("reveal", "open");
        }
    });

    $(document).foundation();
});
```

Comment: Try using 'closed' instead of 'close'

Comment: I did try using closed, but the only result was that `modal2` would open then close almost immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so after some experimentation, I found out that in order to do what I wanted to I had to *bind* the function, not set it in the initialisation phase. Thus:

```
$("#modal2").bind("closed", function() {
    $("#modal1").foundation("reveal", "open");
  });
```

And I set this script after the declaration of the 2 modals.